# Set line width for fplot in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

This code

```
fplot(@sin, [0 4], 'LineWidth', 2)
```

works in MATLAB, but gives error messages using Octave. How to set curve line width for `fplot` in Octave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dimitry’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50782410/7328782) is probably the better one, but you can also find the line handle and modify it:

```
fplot(@sin, [0 4])
h = findobj(gca, 'type', 'line');
set(h, 'LineWidth', 2)
```

Comment: I believe this is better.

Answer (score 2):

Octave is riddled with bugs in less frequently used areas. That's probably one of those.

Use normal `plot` function instead.

```
%get data
[x,y]=fplot(@sin, [0 4]);
%or
x=0:0.1:4; y=sin(x); 

%plot data
plot(x,y, 'LineWidth', 10)
%or
l=plot(x,y);
set(l,'LineWidth', 10)
```

Comment: Note: Having two output arguments for `fplot` is depreciated by Mathworks. MATLAB R2018a also warns about its removal in a future release and recommends to use `XData` and `YData` properties instead.